# What is the significance of missing parameters on the 'git push' command?

Tags: git, version-control, git-push

What is the significance of the following commands:

1. `git push`
2. `git push origin`
3. `git push origin master`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git push <remote> <refspec>
```

This command pushes some things from the local repository to a remote repository. `<remote>` can be the name of a configured remote or a full URL to a remote git repository.

`<refspec>`, in its general form is an optional `+` followed by `<src>:<dst>` where `<src>` is the name of a local branch, tag or commit id and `<dst>` is the name of a remote branch or tag to push to. If `:<dst>` is omitted, it is equivalent to `<src>:<src>`. This means that `git push origin master` is equivalent to `git push origin master:master`. The `+` is used to attempt non fast-forward pushes.

If you don't supply a remote repository (third parameter), then the configured remote for the current branch (if any) will be used, or `origin` if none.

If you don't supply a refspec to push (the fourth parameter) then if there is a configured push refspec for the remote being pushed (config variable: `remote.<remotename>.push`) then that is used, otherwise the behaviour depends on the setting of the config variable `push.default`.

The default is `matching` which pushes all local branches which match (by name) a remote branch on the remote being pushed to.

Other options for `push.default` are `nothing` (which does nothing), `upstream` or `tracking` which pushes the current branch to its configured upstream branch and `current` which pushes the current branch to an identically named branch on the remote.

Comment: +1 A really excellent answer - in particular, the behaviour when you omit the refspec in a `git push` is very frequently misunderstood.